# Does 1 >= 2 ? console.log("123"): null; create memory leak?

Tags: javascript, typescript

i have the question to this statement `1 >= 2 ? console.log("123"): null;`

Does the statement create a memory leak because of "null"? I can write the code like this instead of an if statement.

Best regards,

Comment: why would you think it would create a memory leak? short answer is: it doesn't

Comment: Most likely there won't be memoryleak due to this code. But, you should not use ternary operator _instead of_ `if .. else` statement, use the operator only where an operator is demanded, anywhere else, use `if..else`. Notice, that ternary operator returns a value, which you're supposed to use, in your code you're not using that value.

Comment: In JavaScript you don't allocate any memory, it uses garbage collection to clean up when things go out of scope, your example is meaningless and there is no usage context.

Comment: let a minifier minify your code, don't write code like that. If you write such code, then the person who will have to dig through that will hate you; and there is a good chance that you will be that person.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JavaScript, values exists as long as you can *reference* (access) them. A memory leak is, if you keep a reference to thigs that you actually don't need anymore. In your case however, `null` never gets stored somewhere, so it gets thrown away directly after that statement executed. There is no memory leak.

---

As a sidenote, there is no reason to use a ternary at all here. That can be written in a cleaner way using an if statement:

```
  if(1 >= 2) console.log("123");
```